# Proper way to generalize data fields based on enumerated type

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

Using one fixed structure we can write

```
data Stats = Stats { lines :: !Int, words :: !Int }

instance Num Stats where
    fromInteger x = Stats x x
    (Stats a b) + (Stats a' b') = Stats (a + a') (b + b')
```

we can create some dynamic structure to achieve the generalized version

```
newtype Stats a = Stats { unStats :: [Int] } -- or Map, Vector, ...

instance forall a . (Enum a, Bounded a) => Num (Stats a) where
    fromInteger = Stats . replicate sz
                  where sz = fromEnum (maxBound::a) - fromEnum (minBound::a) + 1
    (Stats a) + (Stats b) = Stats $ zipWith (+) a b

(¨) :: forall a . (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => Int -> a -> Stats a
x ¨ u = Stats $ map (\k -> if k == u then x else 0) [minBound .. maxBound :: a]
```

and use as

```
data TextStats = Lines | Words deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

someTextStats :: Stats TextStats
someTextStats = 1 ¨Lines + 5 ¨Words
```

the former way is static (eg. the unit measurement function would be) but the later is not in the sense that defined structure should be traversed at runtime.

Exists some way apart from Template Haskell? Thk!

Comment: Anonymous, can you explain your -1?

Comment: Second anonymous, can you explain your -1?

Comment: Third anonymous, can you explain your -1?

Comment: Fourth anonymous, can you explain your -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I asked five years ago, I was looking for a way for the aggregate composite function to be fully formed at compile time, rather than iterated at run time.

One way to do this could be:

(Some preambles)

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses
           , FlexibleInstances
           , FunctionalDependencies
           , ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Text.Printf
```

An accumulator is some value that is updated for each new value delivered

```
class Accumulator a v | a -> v where
  accumulate :: a -> v -> a
```

Since we will want to compose multiple accumulators, it seems useful to define a terminator

```
data Nop v = Nop

instance Accumulator (Nop v) v where
  accumulate _ _ = Nop
```

Any accumulator will consist of a projection and an aggregate function. Then we can define for convenience

```
data Prj a v n = Accumulator a v =>
     Prj { prjValue :: n
         , prjAcc   :: n -> n -> n
         , prjPrj   :: v -> n
         , prjNext  :: a
         }

instance Accumulator a v => Accumulator (Prj a v n) v where
  accumulate (Prj n acc prj a) v = Prj (acc n (prj v)) acc prj $ accumulate a v
```

Now, as an example, we can define the following generic accumulators

```
countAcc :: Accumulator a v => a -> Prj a v Int
countAcc = Prj 0 (+) (const 1)

minAcc, maxAcc :: (Bounded n, Ord n, Accumulator a v) => (v -> n) -> a -> Prj a v n
minAcc  = Prj maxBound min
maxAcc  = Prj minBound max

sumAcc, sum2Acc :: (Num n, Accumulator a v) => (v -> n) -> a -> Prj a v n
sumAcc  = Prj 0 (+)
sum2Acc = Prj 0 (\u u' -> u + u' * u')
```

For example, let's suppose we have a warehouse

```
data Item = Item { itemName   :: String
                 , itemStock  :: Int
                 , itemWeight :: Double
                 }
```

With the following data

```
warehouse = [ Item "apple"  12 0.1
            , Item "orange" 21 0.12
            , Item "melon"   9 2.23
            ]
```

We could define the following statistics ( **which will be a compiled function, i.e., internal operations can be optimized, since it does not iterate** )

```
myStats = countAcc
        $ minAcc itemStock  $ maxAcc  itemStock
        $ sumAcc itemStock  $ sum2Acc itemStock
        $ sumAcc itemWeight $ Nop
```

Extracting then the concrete values for our data would be (a more convenient pattern matching projection could be defined)

```
Prj  items _ _ (
 Prj minItems   _ _ (Prj maxItems _ _ (
 Prj sumItems   _ _ (Prj sum2Items _ _ (
 Prj sumWeights _ _ _))))) =
      foldr (flip accumulate) myStats warehouse
```

And running

```
main = do

  let avg, std :: Double
      avg  = fromIntegral sumItems / fromIntegral items
      std  = sqrt ( fromIntegral sum2Items / fromIntegral items + avg**2 )

  printf (unlines [ "%i item types"
                       , "min availability is %i"
                       , "max availability is %i"
                       , "there are a total of %i items"
                       , "average availability is %0.2f +/- %0.2f items"
                       , "the total weight of the goods is %0.2f" ])
              items minItems maxItems sumItems avg std sumWeights
```

we get

```
3 item types
min availability is 9
max availability is 21
there are a total of 42 items
average availability is 14.00 +/- 5.10 items
the total weight of the goods is 2.45
```

(Aside, better notation)

Adding **UndecidableInstances** and **TypeOperators** we can write a type operator concatenating the report results

```
data r :% r' = r :% r'
infixr 7 :%
class Values a r | a -> r where
  values :: a -> r
instance Values a n' => Values (Prj a v n) (n :% n') where
  values (Prj n _ _ a) = n :% values a
instance Values (Nop v) () where
  values _ = ()
```

now, we can write the expected aggregated values as they was defined

```
items :% minItems :% maxItems :% sumItems :% sum2Items :% sumWeights :% () =
  values $ foldr (flip accumulate) myStats warehouse
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach works if you use `RankNTypes`, `ScopedVariables` and you don't try to use double-quotes as an operator name:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

newtype Stats a = Stats { unStats :: [Integer] } -- or Map, Vector, ...
  deriving (Show)

instance forall a . (Enum a, Bounded a) => Num (Stats a) where
    fromInteger = Stats . replicate sz
                  where sz = fromEnum (maxBound::a) - fromEnum (minBound::a) + 1
    (Stats a) + (Stats b) = Stats $ zipWith (+) a b

(€) :: forall a . (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => Integer -> a -> Stats a
x € u = Stats $ map (\k -> if k == u then x else 0) [minBound .. maxBound :: a]

data TextStats = Lines | Words deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

test = 3 € Lines + 5 € Words
```

I also changed the list to contain Integers instead of Ints. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: My approach is working without `RankNTypes` and using `"` (diaeresis). My *dynamic* approach is working, I'm looking for a static one... but thk.